# React - Styled components returns an [object Object]

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, react-redux

I am using ReactHtmlParser and Styled components inside an array, when I try to create a Button component using Styled Components it returns [object Object], I assume I am using an object inside a string so it returns [object Object] but how do I get rid of this problem? https://ibb.co/bvk8LjN

```
const Button = styled.button`
  color: palevioletred;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 10px;
`;


function JavaScriptLessonObject() {
    return (
        [
            {
                titleName: "Creating Your First JavaScript",
                heading: 'Ready. Set. JavaScript!',
                iconName: faDotCircle,
                description: [
                    `
                    <h2 class="title_description">Let’s start</h2>
                    Let’s start with the basics and add some JavaScript to a webpage. </span>

                    <div>
                        <div>
                            <p>Heads up!<p>
                            <p>You can put the script tag anywhere in the HTML document.</p>
                            ${<Button> Button </Button>}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                 `
                ],
            },
        ]
    );
}


{
    ReactHtmlParser(this.props.lesson[this.state.indexDescription]["description"])
}
```

Comment: What do you want to be there instead? You're creating a string, so what text is the desired output?

Comment: How can I then solve this problem?